# How do I pass a redux dispatch function into a smart component without using connect()?

Tags: react-redux, jestjs

I am using pepperoni-app-kit as a starting point and now have smart components connected with react-redux that I would like to test using jest. My problem is the dispatch function which when connected using connect is called from my module under test as dispatch(action) but when called one level up (without connect) would always be called as dispatch(state, action).

So I can use a line like this in my test code:

```
const [newState] = dispatch(initialState, Actions.update_timeAtProperty(0));
```

but now I want to pass the dispatch function into my smart component like this:

```
const tree = renderer.create(
  <BeaconView dispatch={dispatch} />
).toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

so my problem is that the dispatch function I am passing requires both state and action, but within the component under test (which is normally called within react-redux) dispatch is only ever called with a single argument, action. The connect() function tells the dispatch function which parts of my state store to use, but I can't figure out how to do that when outside the connected component.

Answer (score 0):

You can try binding the first argument of `dispatch` to your store:

```
<BeaconView dispatch={dispatch.bind(null, store)} />
```

Comment: I figured this out. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.

In pepperoni-app-kit there is a test function provided for use by test code only that passes an action through all reducers. It happens to be called "dispatch" and takes two arguments (state, action) which means it is really a reducer.

In my code (also derived from pepperoni-app-kit) I am dispatching actions using a dispatch function that only requires the action to be passed because it already knows what store it is dealing with and the store knows about state.

Instead of trying to pass the dispatch(state, action) function down to my components (really a reducer), I imported a redux store itself and now pass the store.dispatch function down to the unit under test.